# Hibernate: Criteria API vs. QueryDsl

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, querydsl

I have some experience with Criteria API but I have never used QueryDsl before. What I want to ask is what are the advantages/disadvantages of using QueryDsl instead of Criteria API? Especially I want to learn which one is more suitable for huge databases(I mean complex queries).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Querydsl is

- more compact
- more typesafe (at least compared to Hibernate Criteria)
- closer to JPQL syntax
- also available for other backends

This answer is biased since I am a Querydsl contributor.

Comment: Could you explain how is it more type safe? With TypedQuery(https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) we can get typesafety even with Criteria API. isn't it so?

Comment: Currently QueryDSL is stuck with hibernate versions < 5.2, and no commits since 8 months ago: https://java.libhunt.com/compare-jooq-vs-querydsl

Comment: @timo What about performance? Hibernate provides default caching for a session. And I found, queries which needed pagination, performs better (as it seems DSL making extra queries which I do not need) in case of Hibernate criteria (on same DB config). Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

QueryDSL is a level of abstraction above criteria; Also, it is more similar to SQL so it might be easier to learn for people who have not touched Criteria before.